How to get rid of indentation with trivlist continuing in a new page
Newbie to LaTeX.
I've used \trivlist to list out my items, but as the list expands to a new page, there is some indentation which throws off the entire format of the list. Can someone please help me out with this?
Code
\begin{trivlist}
\item
.... 
....
\item.... is cost-effective data warehousing \ \
\item blah blah
\end{trivlist}


Edit: Adding a compilable example
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}

% Paquetes
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[style = apa, backend = biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace}



% Recursos bibliográficos
\addbibresource{ref.bib}


% Formato de página
\geometry{a4paper, left=3.5cm,right=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm}


\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no line in header area
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} % page number in the right footer
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} % page number in the right footer
}

% Tesis
\begin{document}

\input{frontmatter/frontmatter}

\mainmatter
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{mainmatter/intro}
\input{mainmatter/problematica}
\input{mainmatter/rev literatura}

\printbibliography

\end{document}


please provide an example that shows your problem. the indentation used by lists is completely unaffected by page breaking so it is hard to understand your question as written

@DavidCarlisle I've edited the question properly to reflect the changes. Is it clearer now?

@user766320 Your question would be easier to understand if you would provide a compilable test file including a class and the necessary packages.

Are you using a two-sided class?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz looked through the template's file and it uses something called \documentclass. I just chose a random template off of overleaf because I'm a total newbie

Please add a compilable example so we can check ourself. If your class is two sides, it can have different margins for even and odd pages.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz does this edit help?

Book uses a two-sided layout by default. Do you intent to print your thesis one- or two-sided?

I intend to print it 2 sided

Then the margins should be different on odd and even pages. What you see is the correct layout. Your list is not indented.

Just as a test, you could (temporarily) use \documentclass[12pt, a4paper,oneside]{book}. This should give the same margins on all pages and the items of your list should be below each other.

the different margins are completely unrelated to the list, you would see the same if you just had a simple long paragraph

Your new example is slightly better but still not a useful example to show your problem as no one can run it as  \input{mainmatter/intro} only you have those files, you should always make self contained examples that just have enoughto show the problem and don't use unrelated packages or files that are not provided.

Note that trivlist is not intended to be used directly in a document it is a base  list for defining other environments (center, verbatim, .....)
